# #include(ing) files, variable name with now type error C++

Tags: c++, class, object

Sorry for the strange title, wasn't quite sure what to call it, anyway, here is my question:

I am having an error message:

> pserver.h:27: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of '`myHashMap`' with no type
>   
> pserver.h:27: error: expected '`;`' before '`<`' token

referencing this line in pserver.h:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class myPserver {
public:
    //
private:
    myHashMap<string, int> theMap; // line 27
};
```

Where the `myHashMap<K, V>` class is defined in a separate file as

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class myHashMap {
    //
};
#include "hashmap.hpp"
```

The header file for this class is included in pserver.h.

So why won't the compiler recognize `myHashMap<string, int>` as a type?

Comment: More code! What is in hashmap.hpp?

Comment: @Bob Fincheimer hashmap.hpp defines the myHashMap class

Comment: That makes no sense. You show `myHashMap` being defined in some file that then `#include`s hashmap.hpp, so how could `myHashMap` be defined again in hashmap.hpp?

Comment: @ildjarn His methods for the template are defined in the `hpp`, not the class.

Answer (score 0):

You either:

- Forgot `#include <string>`
- Need to use `std::string` instead of `string`
- Need a using declaration for `std::string`
- Need a using directive for `namespace std`
- Didn't *properly* include the header containing your `myHashMap` template into pserver.h

Or some combination of the above.

Comment: I have `#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include "pserver.h"
` in my .cpp file

Comment: It is better to scope your types on header files rather than to use a namespace via "using". This will pollute the namespace of other files including the header.

Comment: @dubyaa : pserver.h uses `std::string`, so it should `#include <string>` without relying on other source files to get the includes correct. Likewise, pserver.h uses `std::string`, so it should fully qualify the class name without relying on other source files to have a using directive/declaration. Your code is sloppy, and that's why it's failing.

Comment: @dubyaa - they have to be included in the header file where you are declaring the "theMap".

Comment: I tried adding `#include <string>` to the header file, and using `std::string` and every which way it seems

Comment: @dubyaa : Then lack of inclusion or circular inclusion (as AndreyT mentioned) is likely the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler obviously does not know what `myHashMap` is. You either forgot to include the declaration of `myHashMap` into `pserver.h` (even though you claim that you did include it), or your header files are suffering from circular inclusion problem. Also, could it be that `myHashMap` is declared as a member of some namespace?

It doesn't look like the problem has anything to do with `std::string`, contrary to what other posters suggested. Although the problem with `std::string` might be there, the error messages you quoted are caused by the compiler not seeing the declaration of `myHashMap`.